# Selecting "grandchild"

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress

I have a challenging question!

Let's see three possible scenarios

Scenario 1

```
<div class="entry-content">
   <p><a href="#"><img src="#"></a></p>
</div>
```

Scenario 2

```
<div class="entry-content">
   <p>&nbsp;</p>
   <p><a href="#"><img src="#"></a></p>
</div>
```

Scenario 3

```
<div class="entry-content">
   <p>&nbsp;</p>
   <p>text</p>
   <p><a href="#"><img src="#"></a></p>
</div>
```

The number of `<p>` or other items would be undefined. How could I select ONLY the first img to do a "display:none;"?

My guess is I have to take as parent the .entry-content, but if I do a img:first-child, it takes the `<p>` as parent and would be non-displaying all pictures if there are more. That's why should be something like the grandfather :D If we have to use other language instead of CSS, I am open minded of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to do this with pure CSS, but it's pretty straightforward in jQuery, which you most likely already have loaded on the page anyway:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('.entry-content img').first().hide();
});
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/pq7rwfv3/

Comment: Many thanks Peter! I did try your demo and works perfectly!! :) It's a shame I don't have access to the code right now to try it. I will confirm in a few hours.

Best, Frede

Answer (score 0):

add this function in your theme's functions.php

```
function Remove_image_tags($content) {
// for example above function getting data by paramets 
$content = "this is something with an <img src=\"test.png\"/> in it.";
 $content = preg_replace("/<img[^>]+\>/i", " ", $content); 
  return $content;
 }
```

it will return

```
this is something with an in it.
```