# Use of .first() in a loop (Wordpress)

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I have a Wordpress-JQUERY question. I am trying to use a piece of code like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
        jQuery(document).ready(function($){
            $("article").each(function(){
                $('.entry-content img').first().hide();
            });
        });

</script>
```

I want to hide all the first image of every post (`<article>`) on a blog page.

My code works almost perfect. The only problem is I have to change the `.first()` method for someone else because it only works the first time.

It has to be done by JQUERY. CSS doesn't work this time for what I am looking for. If you want to know why, I have another question that relates to this matter:

[Selecting "grandchild"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25313238/selecting-grandchild)

Thanks!

Comment: `$('article .entry-content').find('img:first').hide();`?

Comment: No he want hide the first image for each article, and his code and your code only hide the first article image

Comment: @Arthur it doesn't, `find()` applies selector context, so for each `article .entry-content` in the collection, it finds the first `img`, and hides it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the first image on THIS element because you loop all 'article' tags but for each, you select the first '.entry-content img' on all the document, so it's all the same you hide.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
        jQuery(document).ready(function($){
            $("article").each(function(){
                $('.entry-content img', $(this)).first().hide();
            });
        });

</script>
```

Comment: No problem :) put your question on resolved for futur reader :)